How to use built-in passes in LLVM-18 with opt?
Here's an example code :
#include<stdio.h>

void loop_print() {
    for (int i = 7; i*i < 1000; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}

int main() {
    loop_print();
    return 0;
}

Then I use the following command to transform the code, aiming to apply the indvars: Canonicalize Induction Variables pass :
clang -O0 -emit-llvm -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -S main.c -o main.ll
opt -passes=indvars main.ll -S -o new_main.ll

I expected the new_main.ll to be the same as the output of clang -O2 -emit-llvm -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -S main.c -o o2_main.ll, where the loop would be transformed into 25 lines of printf. However, it didn't change! new_main.ll remains identical to main.ll. And there are no errors or warnings.
Expected:
; Function Attrs: nofree nounwind uwtable
define dso_local void @loop_print() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %1 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 7)
  %2 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 8)
  %3 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 9)
  %4 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 10)
  %5 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 11)
  %6 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 12)
  %7 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 13)
  %8 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 14)
  %9 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 15)
  %10 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 16)
  %11 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 17)
  %12 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 18)
  %13 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 19)
  %14 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 20)
  %15 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 21)
  %16 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 22)
  %17 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 23)
  %18 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 24)
  %19 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 25)
  %20 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 26)
  %21 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 27)
  %22 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 28)
  %23 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 29)
  %24 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 30)
  %25 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 31)
  ret void
}

Actual (Obviously no transformation):
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define dso_local void @loop_print() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 7, ptr %1, align 4
  br label %2

2:                                                ; preds = %10, %0
  %3 = load i32, ptr %1, align 4
  %4 = load i32, ptr %1, align 4
  %5 = mul nsw i32 %3, %4
  %6 = icmp slt i32 %5, 1000
  br i1 %6, label %7, label %13

7:                                                ; preds = %2
  %8 = load i32, ptr %1, align 4
  %9 = call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef @.str, i32 noundef %8)
  br label %10

10:                                               ; preds = %7
  %11 = load i32, ptr %1, align 4
  %12 = add nsw i32 %11, 1
  store i32 %12, ptr %1, align 4
  br label %2, !llvm.loop !6

13:                                               ; preds = %2
  ret void
}

My LLVM version is 18.1.8 release, OS is Ubuntu:22.04, and I'm feeling quite confused about this issue, because using opt main.ll -passes=dot-cfg successfully exports the .dot files for both functions.
Additionally, can someone teach me how to print the passes I just wrote and registered using opt ... -help in LLVM-18?
And here is a Dockerfile that can help you easily build LLVM 18 image to do some experiments.
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y lsb-release wget software-properties-common gnupg
# install llvm-18 with official script
RUN wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
RUN chmod +x llvm.sh
RUN ./llvm.sh 18 all
RUN rm -f https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/clang++-18 /usr/bin/clang++
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/clang-18 /usr/bin/clang
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-config-18 /usr/bin/llvm-config
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/lli-18 /usr/bin/lli
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/opt-18 /usr/bin/opt

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["/bin/bash"]

Thanks a lot!

Partial answer: Print current pass pipeline with --print-pipeline-passes or --debug-pass-manager. Their outputs are a bit different. Print all available passes by using the --print-passes option. Hope this helps.

use --print-pipeline-passes with opt, Got it ! Thank you @Shraiysh
